# Determining consistency for every $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the matrix

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
      1 & 0 & -3         \\[0.55ex]
      -1 & 0 & 3
\end{array}\right]$$

Basically I can see that adding row 1 to the other row will result in an all zero row. What is wrong with this? According to my notes I just need to show that this set is consistent and I can do that pretty easily I thought. My book says that this is not consistent for all $b$ but how do I know or prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this, **for this choice of $b$**. However, for other choices of $b$, you will get zeroes in the first two entries of the second row but not the third; that is inconsistent. Why? Because it represents the equation $0x + 0y = k$, where $k\neq 0$, which is of course ridiculous.

Comment: But now this is really confusing because what about a matrix of all 1s, wouldn't it be inconsistent if all the bs were 0?

Comment: No, $x + y = 0$ is a perfectly valid equation.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I will have to take note of this special case. Is there an easy to memorize list of conditions for a set being consistent or inconsistent?

Comment: There is only one inconsistent equation that appears in linear algebra, $0x_1 + \dots + 0x_n = k$ where $k \neq 0$.

Comment: But I mean when I want to prove it I have to find the reduced row echelon form don't I? And then I know that if there are no 0 0 0 = non zero than it is consistent. This doesn't fit that until I plug in all numbers and see that one of them (0) doesn't work. Or is this the only case that I really have to worry about where I have a single line with a single variable?

Comment: Regardless of your choice of $b$ (the vector on the right hand side of the vertical line), the row reduced echelon form will be the same. So if the row reduced echelon form of the matrix contains at least one row of zeroes, you will get an inconsistent system, if it doesn't contain a row of zeroes, it is a consistent system.

Comment: In general? I am not sure what you mean, I can have a consistent equation with a row of zeros can't I? In like a 5x5 for example.

Comment: Not if the right hand side is non-zero. The size of the matrix is irrelevant.